# Hide horizontal scrollbar caused by specific div

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

i've got the next html:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

The container div is 1050px wide and includes only the shadow background that is repeated vertically.

The content div is 950px wide, is positioned at the middle of container div (horizontal) and includes content.

What do I need - that a horizontal scroll bar appears only if the browser window is smaller than content div, but container div shall not cause scroll bar to appear. How can i make it?

overflow-x:hidden does not work.

Thx

http://jsfiddle.net/98Eqf/1/

Comment: Could you please post the css you have as well and maybe create a http://jsfiddle.net as well?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/98Eqf/ here it is. Now the scroll appears if the window goes smaller, than grey div. I need it to appear if it goes smaller as red div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/98Eqf/2/

Comment: No, i Need the scroll not inside the div, but the normal browser scroll. If the browser window is less then 950px wide - scroll appears. Otherwise - no. But now it appears if window is less then 1050px wide.

Comment: So whats the problem? body {overflow-x: auto;}

Comment: look here jsfiddle.net/98Eqf i dont want the scroll to appear, if the window is smaller than grey div

Comment: Ok, I think you want to get this feature: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/98Eqf/2/ I scaled it down for the fiddle. And removed the most outer container, I didn't see any point for that..

Comment: Thnx, it works at jsfiddle, but i've got full page body background that need to be aligned with container div. I'f i'm trying to do it with auto margins, the body background gets misaligned in small browser window... the container div must always stay at the middle of the page. And auto margins force it to float at left side if the window is small

Comment: Hmm, basically you got your answer. Since you provided a small case of code, to get an idea how it works. Why not add the full page code and your specific problem? Show me the code full code or live example.

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/NaSwF/13/ the shadow div must not make  scroll apear

Comment: background-position: 0 0; = background-position: center; btw. But anyways, I think this is what you meant: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/NaSwF/14/ edit: You will probably want the top_stripe.png to be aligned.. Well, using margin-left:; and similar to put things in the center, is WRONG! I got you the same effect you were looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/NaSwF/15/ also if you will run into issues with css opacity, then use jQuery and .fadeTo() function.

Comment: Thx, Kalle, but I really need to align it with a background. The semi-transparent image was just an example. In my specific case it can not be done with opacity. Ok, if you say, that negative margins and so are wrong, i'll try to find a solution with auto margins

Comment: Well, no. They are not wrong directly, but its wrong to use them to put some containers to center. As far as for scrolling and layouting goes, this question is solved. But for a specific layout problem make a new question with the "html" tag and I will surely help. Currently, with the examples you are asking for ideas. That's what you got. But if you have more specific problem with certain layout, then you must show us that, otherwise we cant help you :/

Comment: Technically you are not asking again, but you are asking about different thing. "Asking again" is not allowed. Finish this question off, as the horizontal scrollbar issue was basically solved ;)

Comment: Hi, Kalle, let's say, I've refined the question, because i think nobody have completely understood, what i've asked about ) Ok, the shadow div does not force a scroll, but i still can not align it with background.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using a media query then, to check if the browser is 950px wide and then make the scrollbar appear. That'll allow you to use `overflow-x:hidden;` while it's larger and then once it becomes smaller you can just do `overflow-x:scroll;` and make the bar appear.

Comment: thnx, i'll try it out... but i'm still looking for easier way (i'm afraid of browser compatibility failures)